# Local changes due to svn switch

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I had some local changes in my workspace , 3 Weeks of work and i last tryed to switch with "svn switch".

i dont know what happens but my workspace project get an old version of project the one in the trunk i tryed to switch to. 
I again switched to another tag and same thing happened.
The issue is i did multiple svn switches and i still hope that i can undo all these changes and get back my project with my local changes.

The ide is eclipse project java/flex and svn

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to restore changes from local history by right clicking on your project and selecting Restore from Local History.

Team plugin also lets you view history. Simply open Team view --> History --> local revisions.

Also, check this out, how to restore from eclipse history:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_is_the_workspace_local_history_stored%3F

Your eclipse history should be available in workspace at folder:
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history/

Comment: When you say close up a working copy, you mean what exactly ? Disconect from versioning ?